# Error to use the template @akveo/ng2-completer

Tags: angular, nebular

I try to run an Angular app that use the template [AKVeo](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/?utm_source=akveo_website&utm_medium=hompage&utm_campaign=github_block) but through the next error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/components/completer-cmp.d.ts(54,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/components/completer-cmp.d.ts(55,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/components/completer-cmp.d.ts(56,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/components/completer-cmp.d.ts(57,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/components/completer-cmp.d.ts(65,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/components/completer-cmp.d.ts(66,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/components/completer-cmp.d.ts(67,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-completer.d.ts(42,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-completer.d.ts(43,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-completer.d.ts(44,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-completer.d.ts(45,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-completer.d.ts(46,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-input.d.ts(27,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-input.d.ts(28,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-list.d.ts(32,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-list.d.ts(33,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-row.d.ts(13,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@akveo/ng2-completer/src/directives/ctr-row.d.ts(14,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ng2-smart-table/lib/components/tbody/tbody.component.d.ts(29,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

Some solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tsconfig.ts add:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true,
}
```

Comment: it just hides the issue. But when table is loaded, browser will hange

Answer (score 0):

the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "qax-ui",
  "version": "4.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-bundle": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@nebular/auth": "4.1.2",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "^4.1.2",
    "@nebular/security": "4.1.2",
    "@nebular/theme": "^4.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-mega-simple-drag-drop-list": "^1.0.8",
    "ngx-smart-table": "^2.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "github:angular/web-animations-js#release_pr208",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "ng2-completer": "^3.0.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```